# Execute a program when a USB stick is removed

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb-flash-drive, automation

The title says it all. Basically, I want to unmount a TrueCrypt volume when the USB stick with the keyfile on it is removed (and, ideally, shut down the computer as well).

There used to be a program that does that (Truemounter http://www.truemounter.de/) but it seems to be abandoned and apparently didn't work properly under Windows 7 anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: If all else fails, you can write a script/program that periodically checks for existence of the keyfile (`cmd.exe`, Python, etc).

Answer (score 6):

**[USB Safely Remove](http://safelyremove.com/)** has such a feature: it can start a program when a USB device is removed.

> Another USB Safely Remove feature that
>   distinguishes it from similar software
>   is starting any applications not only
>   after connecting a device, but also
>   **before removing it**. The autorun
>   feature allows you to set up data
>   backup before disconnecting a
>   removable hard drive, to run Total
>   Commander with the contents of the
>   pen-drive, **automatically unmount an
>   encrypted TrueCrypt drive before
>   disconnecting the USB media**, etc.

[image]

USB Safely Remove works great on Windows 7 (also in 64-bits).

Comment: +1 Nice. I never even knew anything like this existed.