# Can I enable AutoRun for specific USB drives only in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, autorun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to make a (Windows 7) executable automatically run when I put in my thumb drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/485616/is-it-possible-to-make-a-windows-7-executable-automatically-run-when-i-put-in)

I was looking for a "somewhat safe" method to automatically start a program (in Windows 7) when I connect **a specific** USB stick.

Now, I know, that it's a good idea to generally disable AutoRun for removable devices for security reasons (and I know, how to enable or disable this globally), but for my convenience it would be nice if one could enable it for a (few) specific device(s) only.

I fancy, that this device then has to contain some magic file or ID or label or whatever and only if that is found present on the stick, then AutoRun (or some other specific program) is activated. Does something like that exist? Any suggestion?