# Schedule a task to run upon connection to usb port

Tags: windows-8, usb, windows-10-preview, windows-task-scheduler

I would like to trigger an event when **any** device is plugged into a usb port.

I can't find anything relevant in event viewer.

I am running Windows 8, but would like it to be compatible with Windows 10.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting scheduled task by detecting connection of USB drive](http://superuser.com/questions/219401/starting-scheduled-task-by-detecting-connection-of-usb-drive)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Not a duplicate: there are no satisfactory answers for me over there. Additionally, they are discussing Windows 7, not 8/10.

Comment: Still the same question (IMO anyway). If you'd like newer/different answers to the existing question please consider [placing a bounty on it](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) and it will give you a chance to explain why you're not satisfied with the existing answers.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Started a bounty.