# WmiEvent for any usb device

Tags: usb, powershell, wmi, win32

I am following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/845411/234529), which contains

```
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

and

```
$newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

This works when I insert or remove a USB flash drive. (I'm thinking it's because of `VolumeChange`) I would like to detect insertion or removal of *any* USB device though, not only drives. Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, you have to use `DeviceChangeEvent` instead of `VolumeChangeEvent` :

```
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_DeviceChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier deviceChange
```

and

```
$newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier deviceChange
```

Note that the SourceIdentifier is just the name of event subscription so you can keep "volumeChange" if you prefer.