# How to pause service and alert when volume is not ready?

Tags: script, login

Under Windows 10, would it be possible to display a pop-up and pause a sync service when a specific usb drive is not found?

Best regards,

Gilles

Comment: I grabbed this, would you use it?
Get-Volume -UniqueId <???>
(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-volume?view=win10-ps)

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to a system service, it's the service itself that should register
for the event. The only other way to do that is to have a script pause and start
the service when the USB device is introduced/dismounted.
The same approach is to be used to start some sync job that is not a system service.

Here is where it starts getting technical : The tool to use is PowerShell,
and you should write a script that starts the sync when the drive is introduced.

You may find such a script in the post
[Starting scheduled task by detecting connection of USB device](https://superuser.com/a/845411/8672), which you may adapt to your purpose.
That script starts a batch job when the specified drive is introduced.
You may start the script at user logon with the Task Scheduler.